# Sending notifications when button clicked errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to notify my users when someone clicks the going button but I keep getting a couple of errors in my firebase functions logs.

Uncaught Exception &

Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array

```
exports.observeGoing = functions.database.ref('/going/{postId}/{uid}').onCreate((snapshot,context) => {

var postId = context.params.postId;
var uid = context.params.uid;

console.log('User: ' + uid + ' is going to your activity');

return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {

var creatorOfPost = snapshot.val();

admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {

  var userGoing = snapshot.val();

  var payload = {
    notification: {
      body: userGoing.usernames + " is going",
      sound: "default"
    }
  }

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(creatorOfPost.fcmToken, payload)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Successfully send message:', response);
    return response
  })
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
})
})
})
```

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: Can you also provide the stack trace or those errors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Can you share the complete error message? It's difficult to figure what is wrong without that

Comment: Log the value of `creatorOfPost.fcmToken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You reveive that error because `creatorOfPost.fcmToken` can be null

According to the firebase document, the first parameter of [admin.messaging.Messaging.sendToDevice()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging?hl=ja#sendToDevice) cannot be null.

But in your code, there are 2 possibility to violate this precondition.

#### `creatorOfPost.fcmToken` can be null

just do null check before calling `admin.messaging.Messaging.sendToDevice()`

#### `creatorOfPost` can be null

[firebase.database.Reference.once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) returns [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), but it doesnt mean there always be corresponding document.

so, `var creatorOfPost = snapshot.val();` can be null.

maybe you can check like this:

```
return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {
  if (!snapshot.exists()) {
    return; // or do what you would like
  }

  var creatorOfPost = snapshot.val();
  // ...
  // ...
})
```